# Expandablelist child on click listener not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview

The onChildClickListener is not working on my expandable list.

The child layout is made from a custom LinearLayout by code and it adds some other child views into it from xml.

For the xml, all views are set to clickable=false. 
The extended layout (The parent layout of the other views) is not set to anything  clickable - wise since it's in code.

I believe I should set the custom linear layout to clickable false as well but since it's in code I'm not sure to do it

Here is my getChildView method:

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);


        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = new ExtendedContentLinearLayout(context);

convertView).addViewToContentLayout(text);




        ImageView leftImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.child_left_image);
        leftImage.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.folder_));


        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
        childTextView.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Extended LinearLayout:

```
public class ExtendedContentLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View mTrigger;
    private LinearLayout mContent;

    public ExtendedContentLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContent = new LinearLayout(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mTrigger = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_menu_board_expandable_children_outer, this, true);
        this.addView(mContent);
        mTrigger.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public ExtendedContentLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExtendedContentLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        this(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        App.disableTouchEventForDefaultDuration();
        toggleVisibility();
    }

    public void addViewToContentLayout(View view) {
        mContent.addView(view);
        toggleVisibility();
    }


    private void toggleVisibility() {
        if (mContent.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            mContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        mContent = null;
        mTrigger = null;
    }
}
```

The children views xml which I add to the custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/triggerLayout"
        android:background="@color/da_nav_drawer_dark"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:clickable="false"

            android:id="@+id/child_left_image"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="@color/da_white"
            android:id="@+id/childTextView" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setOnChildClickListener` listener on listview? Get more help [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) also.

Comment: Yes this is what I said is not working. It's not being called.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the parent layout to clickable through code:

parent.setClickable(true);

that solved it.

thanks you for all the help